# Constructing a smooth function with derivative constraints

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking to construct a smooth ($C^\infty$) function, $g$ such that $g'(x) = -1$ for $x \le -1$ and $g'(x) =1$ for $x \ge 1$.
I am thinking of setting $g(x) = -x$ for $x \le -1$ and $g(x) = x$ for $x \ge -1$ however I can't think what to use for $-1 < x < 1$.

I have thought about using cos but obviously it needs to "match" the tails at $0$ at $x = 1$ and $-1$ for derivatives greater than and including the 2nd,  so this didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: First find a $C^\infty$ bump function $\phi$  with support $[-1,1]$ and $\int \phi=2$. Then set $g'(x) = -1 + \int_{-1}^x \phi(y)dy$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: @CalvinKhor sorry I'm still unsure - never dealt with bump functions before - how would I go about finding a bump function with integral 2? I was initially thinking of rescaling the example on the wiki page but that integral is out of my ability.

Comment: Your initial thought is exactly correct :) It is a little daunting at first yes, but you can treat that wikipedia page as a black-box (for now). Namely if $\psi$ is the example on that page, you want to set $\phi = 2 \frac{\psi} { \int_{\mathbb R} \psi}$

Comment: @CalvinKhor thanks a lot for your help - sorry if this sounds stupid but how would I compute that integral? As far as I know it doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmm, I guess its not too hard to see using $0≤ \psi \le 1$ that $0<\int_{-1}^1\psi < 2.$ Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $\psi$ to be the "standard bump function" as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) $$\psi(x) = \begin{cases} \exp\Big(-\frac1{1-x^2}\Big) & x\in (-1,1), \\ 0 & x \notin (-1,1).\end{cases} $$

This function is probably the classic example of a $C^\infty$ function with compact support$^1$. One writes $\psi \in C^\infty_c$. The support is clearly $[-1,1]$, and the proof of the smoothness is written out in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) other Wikipedia page.

Its easy to see directly using $0≤ \psi \le 1$ that $0<\int_{-1}^1\psi < 2.$ (For the upper bound, note that either $\phi(x) = 0$, or $\psi(x) = e^{-\left[\substack{\tiny \text{something}\\\tiny\text{positive}}\right]} \le e^0 = 1.)$Set $\phi = \frac{\psi}{\int_{-1}^1 \psi}$. Then $\int\phi = 1$, so we can set
$$ g(x) = \int_0^x \left( -1 + \int_{-1}^{x_1} 2\phi (x_2) dx_2 \right )dx_1. $$

Here is a graph of all these functions(with slightly different names). You can make it run yourself [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/homnklfrqv) but I had to hard-code some parts using a piecewise definition to make Desmos compile in a reasonable time.

[image]

There is a different more general construction using [smooth cut-off functions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Smooth_cutoff_functions)

---

$^1$: the support of a function $f:A\to B$ is the closed set $$\operatorname{supp} f :=\overline{\{ x \in A : f(x) \neq 0 \}}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this - I'm pretty sure I understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: @Yab0i30 You're welcome, glad it helped :) Also, books on distribution theory like Duistermaat and Kolk's will cover this and more.